# XML Documentation on Master page methods

Tags: c#, xml, documentation, master-pages, intellisense

I have created some methods with XML documentation and put them on our master page.

The intellisense is not picking my the xml Documentation.  If I have the same method in the class I am working in, it works just fine.

For the example code below if have this on my master page the intellisense returns ... 
  "bool Test(string str)".

If I have it in my local class I get two lines ...

"bool Test(string str)"
  "This is a test method".

How do I get the xml documentation when the method is located on a master page?

```
/// <summary>
/// This is a test method
/// </summary>
/// <param name="str">string to check</param>
/// <returns>true or false</returns>
public static Boolean Test (string str)
{
  ...
}
```